# Bittrex API market history -- interpreting OrderType

Tags: exchanges, api, bittrex

The [Bittrex API](https://bittrex.com/home/api) has a request to get the market history:

`https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkethistory?market=BTC-DOGE`

which gives a response containing the following fields:

- "Id"
- "TimeStamp"
- "Quantity"
- "Price"
- "Total"
- "FillType"
- "OrderType"

`"OrderType"` can be one of `"BUY"` or `"SELL"`. What does this refer to?

Let's assume it has a value of "SELL". Does this mean:

1. The person who initially placed the order was selling (Seller is Maker).
2. The person who closed the order was selling (Seller is Taker)

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it!

BUY means that the order was the consequence of someone buying at the ask price, as opposed to creating an order at a lower-than-market price.

SELL means that the order was the consequence of someone selling at the bid price, as opposed to creating an order at a higher-than-market price.